# Encoding conditional jump (jecxz) within inline assembly

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I am trying encode a `jecxz` instruction within inline assembly.  The `jexcz` should jump to the next immediate instruction (i.e: the `nop`).

```
int main() {
  asm("lea -24(%rdi), %rcx");
  asm("jecxz $0x00");
  asm("nop");
}
```

But I am getting the following error.

`` gcc -o t main.c
main.c: Assembler messages:
main.c:7: Error: operand type mismatch for `jecxz' ``

What needs to be fixed here?

Comment: `jecxz` doesn't take an immediate value, it takes an 8 bit relative value as a parameter. You usually use a label with [_JECXZ_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html)

Comment: Or something relative to the instruction pointer like `jecxz .` . Hard to tell what you were going for.

Comment: I agree that the example is bit contrived. I just wanted jexcz to jump to the next immediate instruction (i.e: the nop). I guess my understanding of it is wrong. I thought $0x00 would encode the relative distance of the jump.

Comment: You could put a local label on the _NOP_ and use that label in jecxz. Alternatively you could just use `asm("jecxz .+3");` to jump to the _NOP_ . That 3 byte _JECXZ_ should be encoded as `67 e3 00`

Comment: Got it. If you want to add that as an answer I can accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: You can take the information and self answer this question. Please be my guest.

Comment: BTW, changing rcx in basic asm like this is risky.  If you are modifying the value of registers, consider using [extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Answer (score 3):

#### The most compatible solution is to write the line as follows:

```
asm("jecxz nextline; nextline:");
```

#### Regarding the `asm("jecxz .+3")` solution:

In 16-bit mode, a `jcxz` is encoded as `e3 XX` and a `jecxz` is encoded as `67 e3 XX`

In 32-bit mode, a `jecxz` is encoded as `e3 XX` and a `jcxz` is encoded as `67 e3 XX`

In 64-bit mode, a `jrcxz` is encoded as `e3 XX` and a `jecxz` is encoded as `67 e3 XX` (`jcxz` is not available)

(Where `XX` is a signed-byte offset from the *end* of the instruction to the jump target)

So then, the line `asm("jecxz .+3");` would assemble to `67 e3 00` in 16-bit and 64-bit code, and `e3 01` in 32-bit code.  **The 32-bit case would be incorrect**, as it would jump one byte past the end of the instruction, given that the 32-bit form is only two bytes wide.

If we use a label, we cover all three cases.

Answer (score 1):

As per Micheal Petch's comment the correct usage is

```
asm("jecxz .+3");
```

which encodes the relative distance to the next immediate instruction.